# MySQL DATE_SUB not working with a variable but working with a regular value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this part of a query:

```
(@tmpo1245 := CAST( ( ( pm5.`meta_value` - pm4.`meta_value` ) / 86400 ) AS SIGNED ) ) AND
(@mutdate:=DATE_SUB( '2011-06-1', INTERVAL @tmpo1245 DAY ) ) AND
```

Which is causing my query to fail. I know `CAST( ( ( pm5.`meta_value`- pm4.`meta_value`) / 86400 ) AS SIGNED )` is 5, I put it in a select statement to test it. I also know the following query works just fine:

```
(@tmpo1245 := 5 ) AND
(@mutdate:=DATE_SUB( '2011-06-1', INTERVAL @tmpo1245 DAY ) ) AND
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error is with the clause inside the CAST in your query. I guess the data types of pm5.`meta_value` and pm4.`meta_value` your are trying to subtract are not numeric. Hence please cast them decimals first before subtracting. Example code would be as follows.

```
@tmpo1245 := CAST( ( ( 
    CAST( pm5.`meta_value` AS DECIMAL) - CAST( pm4.`meta_value` AS DECIMAL)) / 86400 ) 
    AS SIGNED )
```